# Update Notification without Collasping notification drawer

Tags: android

i have a notification manager that launches an activity when clicked.

```
mBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
               .setOngoing(true)
               .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
               .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
               .setContent(remoteViews)
               .setAutoCancel(false);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Launch.class).putExtra("type", 0), 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

the function performed in this can also be be asynchronous depending on the users preference. I want to update the notification to an ongoing progress. something of this nature:

```
 mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Sending details")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setProgress(100, 0, true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false);
```

when the notification is selected. This is achieved but what i want to do is update the notification from the former to the later without having to first slide up the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

you need **NOTIFICATION_ID** to updated the specific notification.

Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating)